# How to upgrade an existing kubeflow pipeline?

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

In the pipeline UI I use the upload pipeline button to upload new pipelines.

Since the pipeline name is unique, the only way to update is to delete the old pipeline and then to upload a new one.

Is there a better way, maybe to manage a version for a single pipeline name?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using Kubeflow on prem with this [config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/manifests/b37bad9eded2c47c54ce1150eb9e6edbfb47ceda/kfdef/kfctl_existing_arrikto.0.7.1.yaml) and there is no easy way to update a uploaded pipeline. However, I have tried just deploying Kubeflow Pipelines only by following this [doc](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/tree/master/manifests/kustomize) and the UI is more updated and it supports pipeline versioning (sorry but I can't get the screenshot since I already uninstall it). So probably this feature is half-way complete.

Just FYI, I also check the [road map of Kubeflow](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/ROADMAP.md), the pipeline versioning suppose to be ready in 2019 Q4 and will be in Kubeflow v1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running an older version of Kubeflow. The current latest version (v1.0 and beyond) supports Pipeline versioning. No, there's no native pipeline versioning in older Kubeflow versions (at least v0.7 or above). So you either have to manually remove the old pipeline and add the new one each time.

However, I typically bypass having to do this by not uploading the pipelines manually at all. There's a `kfp-server-api` library that you can [check](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

You create a `kfp.Client` object ([link](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.client.html#kfp.Client)), giving it the host address, namespace and other authenticating info, and then use the `upload_pipeline()` call to give a suitable name to your pipeline. Or you can automate the `delete` + `add new pipeline (with same name)` workflow. 
I find this pretty useful!